# Return multiple columns from single (LIMITed) row of associated table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've got a master table `tblAssetMaster A` and a movement table `tblMovement M`.  **I want to pull all the assets and their current location**, so need to grab the most recent movement entry for each.

**Fields**

- A: AssetID, AssetName
- M: MovementID, AssetID, CurrentLocation, LocationUpdated

I've looked at various joins, subqueries, derived queries and I'm getting confused with an overload of information.  What would be the most efficient (simplest) way to retrieve this information.

Comment: explain better add a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Exactly as I wrote, I wanted each asset and their current location.  As I then included the Movement table fields, you can see it has a CurrentLocation and LocationUpdated field, so I just needed to limit the results returned for that table to the most recently updated entry per asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an inner join with the most recent MovementID grouped  by AssetID

```
select  A.AssetID, A.AssetName, M.MovementID, M.CurrentLocation, LocationUpdated
FROM tblAssetMaster A
INNER JOIN tblMovement M ON A.AssetID = M.AssetID
INNER JOIN (
  select 
      M.AssetID
    max(M.MovementID) my_mov_id
  from  tblMovement M
  group by M.AssetID
) T ON T.AssetID = M.AssetID AND T.my_mov_id = M.MovementID
```

Comment: Works fine, but on the 50K master asset records and 5 movement records each, I can't see any discernable difference in time it takes to execute between this and my own solution.  Also this isn't liked by Views (no subqueries in views for some reason).  I need it in a view (not noted in question) so i can grab it easily from Excel.  I'll mark as solution, might comment further once I've added the additional 20+ movements per Asset.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like writing it down in simple turns helps to work it out:

```
SELECT A.AssetID, A.AssetName, M.MovementID, M.CurrentLocation, LocationUpdated
FROM tblAssetMaster A
LEFT JOIN tblMovement M ON 
A.AssetID = M.AssetID AND M.MovementID=

(SELECT MovementID FROM tblMovement M WHERE M.AssetID=A.AssetID ORDER BY LocationUpdated DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Please let me know if there is a more efficient (less work for server) way to do this.

Comment: This works with similar speed to scaisEdge's solution and can be used in a view.